# Operator representation in Fermionic Fock space

Tags: operators, condensed-matter, fermions, many-body, grassmann-numbers

The representation of any operator $F$ in the fermionic Fock space in terms of displacement operators as -
\begin{equation}
F = \int d^2{\bf{\xi}}~f(\xi) D(-\xi)
\end{equation}
where $f(\xi)$ is the weight function and $D(\alpha)$ is the displacement operator and $\xi$ be the Grassmann variable.
For any set $\alpha=\{\alpha_{i}\}$, we can write the displacement operator as
\begin{equation}
D(\alpha)=\exp\Big(\sum_{i}(a^{\dagger}_{i}\alpha_{i}-\alpha^{*}_{i}a_{i})\Big)
\end{equation}
Can anyone explain or prove the above equation for the arbitrary operator $F$?
Reference: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.59.1538

Answer (score 4):

This is explained in equations (57)-(60), which are literally referenced right before the statement in question

> The preceding . . . completeness (57)–(60) of the displacement operators give us a means of expanding an arbitrary operator $F$ in the form

The point is that a single-mode fermionic operator can be expressed as a linear combination of certain basis elements (identity $I$, annihilation operator $a$, creation operator $a^\dagger$, and number operator $a^\dagger a$). Since each of these can be defined as some integral over displacement operators, any linear combination of them can be, as well.

In particular, if
$$I=\int d^2\xi \tilde{f}_I(\xi) D(\xi)\equiv \int d^2\xi f_I(\xi) D(-\xi),$$

$$a= \int d^2\xi f_a(\xi) D(-\xi),$$
$$a^\dagger= \int d^2\xi f_{a^\dagger}(\xi) D(-\xi),$$
and
$$a^\dagger a= \int d^2\xi f_{a^\dagger a}(\xi) D(-\xi),$$ then, for any operator $F=\alpha I+\beta a+\gamma a^\dagger+\epsilon a^\dagger a$, we know that
$$F=\int d^2\xi [\alpha f_I(\xi)+\beta f_a(\xi)+\gamma f_{a^\dagger}(\xi)+\epsilon f_{a^\dagger a} (\xi)] D(-\xi)\equiv \int d^2\xi f(\xi)D(-\xi),$$
where we simply define
$$f(\xi)\equiv \alpha f_I(\xi)+\beta f_a(\xi)+\gamma f_{a^\dagger}(\xi)+\epsilon 
 f_{a^\dagger a} (\xi).$$ Linearity and completeness are very powerful!

Note that I made up some function $\tilde{f}(\xi)=f(-\xi)$ to account for a sign change between equations 57-60 versus the equation in question (96), which was chosen for later convenience.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it.